# How to automatically convert a record in "makeFields" lens format to JSON with fields matching lenses?

Tags: json, haskell, record, haskell-lens

```
data ArticlePreview = ArticlePreview
  { _articlePreviewName          :: T.Text
  , _articlePreviewPerex         :: T.Text
  , _articlePreviewAuthorName    :: T.Text
  , _articlePreviewAuthorUrl     :: T.Text
  , _articlePreviewDate          :: T.Text
  , _articlePreviewCategoryName  :: T.Text
  , _articlePreviewCategoryUrl   :: T.Text
  , _articlePreviewCommentsCount :: Maybe Integer
  } deriving (Show, Eq, Generic)

makeFields ''ArticlePreview
```

I tried Aeson:

```
instance ToJSON ArticlePreview
instance FromJSON ArticlePreview

encodeToString :: ToJSON a => a -> String
encodeToString = CL.unpack . encode
```

Outputs:

```
{"_articlePreviewCommentsCount":17,"_articlePreviewAuthorName":"x","_articlePreviewName":"x","_articlePreviewCategoryName":"x","_articlePreviewAuthorUrl":"x","_articlePreviewCategoryUrl":"x","_articlePreviewDate":"x","_articlePreviewPerex":"x"}
```

Desired output:

```
{"commentsCount":17,"authorName":"x","name":"x","categoryName":"x","authorUrl":"x","categoryUrl":"x","date":"x","perex":"x"}
```

I don't insist on Aeson, but it must be automatic (without manual definition that e.g. `_articlePreviewCommentsCount` maps to `commentsCount`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can derive `FromJSON`/`ToJSON` using template Haskell from [`Data.Aeson.TH`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-7.15/aeson-0.11.2.1/Data-Aeson-TH.html) which allows for some modifications:

```
import Data.Aeson.TH
import Data.Char

deriveJSON
  defaultOptions {fieldLabelModifier = (_head %~ toLower) . drop 15}
  ''ArticlePreview

t :: ArticlePreview
t = ArticlePreview "" "" "" "" "" "" "" (Just 12)
```

Then you get:

```
GHCI> encode t
"{\"name\":\"\",\"perex\":\"\",\"authorName\":\"\",\"authorUrl\":\"\",\"date\":\"\",\"categoryName\":\"\",\"categoryUrl\":\"\",\"commentsCount\":12}"
```

Comment: Works great. I wasn't sure if it would be possible. Thank you :).